# Filling not null values as 1 in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a pyspark dataframe named dataframe_freq as given below,

```
+-----------+----+----+----+----+---+----+
|customer_id|  p1|  p2|  p3|  p4| p5|  p6|
+-----------+----+----+----+----+---+----+
|       null|null| 0.6|   0| 0.4|  0| 0.6|
|          2|   0|null| 0.4|null|0.4|   0|
|       null| 0.5|   0|null|   0|  0| 0.5|
|          4| 0.3|null|   0|   0|  0|null|
|          5| 0.4|null|   0|null|0.4| 0.2|
+-----------+----+----+----+----+---+----+
```

If I want to replace null values I can use,

```
dataframe_freq = dataframe_freq.na.fill('1')
```

But what I want to replace not null values as 1. So my resultant dataframe should be,

```
+-----------+----+----+----+----+---+----+
|customer_id|  p1|  p2|  p3|  p4| p5|  p6|
+-----------+----+----+----+----+---+----+
|       null|null|   1|   1|   1|  1|   1|
|          1|   1|null|   1|null|  1|   1|
|       null|   1|   1|null|   1|  1|   1|
|          1|   1|null|   1|   1|  1|null|
|          1|   1|null|   1|null|  1|   1|
+-----------+----+----+----+----+---+----+
```

Can anyone help??

Comment: homework assignment or coincidence ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51322538/replace-not-null-values-of-spark-dataframe-as-1-using-scala-in-optimized-way

Comment: Not a homework assignment. I am using it in my project.

Comment: But the answer for that question asked is in scala version. I want the pyspark version of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative solution to @Florian 's answer is using comprehension list. I'm using the same data example :

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'x1': [None, '1', None],
                   'x2': ['b', None, '2'],
                   'x3': [None, '0', '3'] })
df = spark.createDataFrame(df)

selection = [F.when(F.col(c).isNull(),F.col(c)).otherwise(F.lit(1)).alias(c) for c in df.columns]

df.select(selection).show()
# +----+----+----+
# |  x1|  x2|  x3|
# +----+----+----+
# |null|   1|null|
# |   1|null|   1|
# |null|   1|   1|
# +----+----+----+
```

You just need to note that both solutions has the same optimized logical plan.

Comment: But they haven't used any for loop there in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51322538/replace-not-null-values-of-spark-dataframe-as-1-using-scala-in-optimized-way ....I am asking this because I have a large dataset of around 1Million rows.. Can't we do it in more optimised way? Sorry If I am wrong.. @eliasah

Comment: I know what I've used. That's my answer in the link. Like I've stated in my answer, it's the same optimized logical plan. This is as optimized as it can get.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
df = pd.DataFrame({'x1': [None, '1', None],
                   'x2': ['b', None, '2'],
                   'x3': [None, '0', '3'] })
df = spark.createDataFrame(df)

for c in df.columns:
    df = df.withColumn(c,F.when(F.col(c).isNull(),F.col(c)).otherwise(F.lit(1)))

df.show()
```

Before:

```
+----+----+----+
|  x1|  x2|  x3|
+----+----+----+
|null|   b|null|
|   1|null|   0|
|null|   2|   3|
+----+----+----+
```

After:

```
+----+----+----+
|  x1|  x2|  x3|
+----+----+----+
|null|   1|null|
|   1|null|   1|
|null|   1|   1|
+----+----+----+
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Is there any way to do it without for loop?I need the pyspark version of this   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/51322538/replace-not-null-values-of-spark-dataframe-as-1-using-scala-in-optimized-way

Comment: @ManiRz they both have the same optimized logical plan in this case but I'll suggest an alternative solution if the question is re-opened