# Filling null and not null values as 0 and 1, respectively to only selected columns in pyspark dataframe

Tags: for-loop, pyspark, subset

For a sample spark df:

```
sdf = ({'id_col': [25, 13, 15],
                   'x2': ['b', None, '2'],
                   'x3': [None, '0', '3'] })
```

which I would to have:

```
sdf = ({'id_col': [25, 13, 15],
                   'x2': [1, 0, 1],
                   'x3': [0, 1, 1] })
```

replace all null with 0, and notnull with 1.

Following the syntax from: [Filling not null values as 1 in pyspark dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51381038/filling-not-null-values-as-1-in-pyspark-dataframe). it went trough all the columns of the sdf. For my case, I need to keep the values of id_col as is but replace with 1 and 0 on cols x2 and x3.

I initially tried the following:

I put the x2 and x3 cols in a list:

list = ['x2','x3']

then applied this:

```
col_selection = [when(col(c).isNull(),0).otherwise(1).alias(c) for c in sdf[[list]].columns]
```

I get the intended 0s and 1s, but I only get the x2 and x3 columns. When I called the sdf, the changes did not happen. If I have 17 columns to go through in a 25-column sdf, can you guide me on how to apply the for loop on only the 17 columns?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible to do one by one

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
import pandas as pd
sdf = pd.DataFrame({'id_col': [25, 13, 15],
                   'x2': ['b', None, '2'],
                   'x3': [None, '0', '3'] })
sdf=spark.createDataFrame(sdf)
sdf.withColumns({"x2":F.when(F.col("x2").isNull(),0).otherwise(1),"x3":F.when(F.col("x3").isNull(),0).otherwise(1)}).show()

#output
+------+---+---+
|id_col| x2| x3|
+------+---+---+
|    25|  1|  0|
|    13|  0|  1|
|    15|  1|  1|
+------+---+---+
```

Note-withColumns is only available in spark version >= 3.3.0

To do in loop

```
lis=['x2','x3']
for a in lis:
  sdf=sdf.withColumn(f"{a}",F.when(F.col(f"{a}").isNull(),0).otherwise(1))
sdf.show()

#output
+------+---+---+
|id_col| x2| x3|
+------+---+---+
|    25|  1|  0|
|    13|  0|  1|
|    15|  1|  1|
+------+---+---+
```

Comment: Thanks for catching that. I was in a hurry changing words and missed that. This is only a sample sdf. I have 20 columns and I already had your method, right now I am only cleaning my code to make it more efficient/readable. One method I thought might work is iterate through each selected columns but when I call the base sdf, I will see the expected 0s and 1s but keeping values of the first four columns.

Comment: Added iteration code too which will work for all columns one by one